# single bit error correction double bit error detection using Hamming code in C language

Tags: c, communication, error-correction, forwarderrorcorrection

I'm doing my project on single bit error correction double bit error detection using C, I got the answer for implementation of Hamming code(7, 4), but I'm facing difficulty to generate shortened Hamming code or extended Hamming code. Can any one suggest the logic how to generate shortened Hamming code for different input length? Thank you...

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I downvoted this question because @Shetty seems to be looking for an easy way of not doing his/her homework.

Answer (score 1):

Wiki links:

[Hamming (7,4)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming(7,4))

[Hamming code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code)

As mentioned in the wiki article, an extended Hamming code adds an additional parity bit to allow single bit correction while still retaining double bit error detection.

A shortened Hamming code has fewer data bits, but this can be emulated by substituting zeroes for the missing data bits in the encoder and decoder.